# Issue sending NMEA commands to Copernicus GPS

Tags: gps, nmea, sparkfun

So I'm hooked up to a sparkfun GPS over a serial port, and I'm able to read the NMEA output just fine- I get the GGA and VTG sentences at 1Hz.

My issue comes in at trying to send commands to the GPS, any set commands invariably result in the invalid command sentence being sent, for example the serial port configuration example in the manual:

$PTNLSPT,04800,8,N,1,4,4*11

results in

$PTNLRPT,V*2A

Furthermore, some query sentences work and some do not- for example, I'm able to query the almanac status, but issuing the query command for version info spits out an invalid command sentence.

Is there something I'm missing with sparkfun's copernicus gps or NMEA?

Comment: The first things I can think of are: Is your NMEA checksum at the end correct?, are you adding the new line character "\n"?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the checksums are correct, otherwise I don't think I'd be getting responses to some of the queries. I have noticed that a few of the checksums in the examples in the sparkfun manual seem to be wrong, at least according to online nmea checksum calculators and double checking by hand. And yes, I'm sending '\r\n' at the end of all the sentences.